# Source position Top and Bottom in OpenAL

Tags: audio, 3d, openal

I tried to put the source position top and bottom this way:

**top:**

```
sourcePos[0]=0f;
sourcePos[1]=-1f;
sourcePos[2]=0f;
```

**bottom:**

```
sourcePos[0]=0f;             
sourcePos[1]=1f;
sourcePos[2]=0f
```

Unfortunately, they seem to be indistinguishable. Moreover, if I change the sourcePos[1] to any other value, I still do not detect any change in  the audio.

However, sourcePos[0] and sourcePos[2] work fine. Why the second position in the source position array does not take any effect?

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Here is the full code:

```
import com.jogamp.openal.*;
import com.jogamp.openal.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class SingleStaticSource {

    static AL al = ALFactory.getAL();

    // Buffers hold sound data.
    static int[] buffer = new int[1];;

    // Sources are points emitting sound.
    static int[] source = new int[1];

    // Position of the source sound.
    static float[] sourcePos = { 0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    // Velocity of the source sound.
    static float[] sourceVel = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    // Position of the listener.
    static float[] listenerPos = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    // Velocity of the listener.
    static float[] listenerVel = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    // Orientation of the listener. (first 3 elements are "at", second 3 are "up")
    static float[] listenerOri = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

    static int loadALData() {

        // variables to load into

        int[] format = new int[1];
        int[] size = new int[1];
        ByteBuffer[] data = new ByteBuffer[1];
        int[] freq = new int[1];
        int[] loop = new int[1];

        // Load wav data into a buffer.
        al.alGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
        if (al.alGetError() != AL.AL_NO_ERROR)
            return AL.AL_FALSE;

        ALut.alutLoadWAVFile("wavdata/FancyPants.wav", format, data, size, freq, loop);
        al.alBufferData(buffer[0], format[0], data[0], size[0], freq[0]);


        // Bind buffer with a source.
        al.alGenSources(1, source, 0);

        if (al.alGetError() != AL.AL_NO_ERROR)
            return AL.AL_FALSE;

        al.alSourcei (source[0], AL.AL_BUFFER,   buffer[0]   );
        al.alSourcef (source[0], AL.AL_PITCH,    1.0f     );
        al.alSourcef (source[0], AL.AL_GAIN,     1.0f     );
        al.alSourcefv(source[0], AL.AL_POSITION, sourcePos, 0);
        al.alSourcefv(source[0], AL.AL_VELOCITY, sourceVel, 0);
        al.alSourcei (source[0], AL.AL_LOOPING,  loop[0]     );


        // Do another error check and return.
        if(al.alGetError() == AL.AL_NO_ERROR)
            return AL.AL_TRUE;

        return AL.AL_FALSE;
    }

            static void setListenerValues() {
                al.alListenerfv(AL.AL_POSITION, listenerPos, 0);
                al.alListenerfv(AL.AL_VELOCITY,    listenerVel, 0);
                al.alListenerfv(AL.AL_ORIENTATION, listenerOri, 0);
            }

            static void killALData() {
                al.alDeleteBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
                al.alDeleteSources(1, source, 0);
                ALut.alutExit();
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                // Initialize OpenAL and clear the error bit.

                ALut.alutInit();
                al.alGetError();

                // Load the wav data.
                if (loadALData() == AL.AL_FALSE)
                    System.exit(-1);

                setListenerValues();

                // Setup an exit procedure.

                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                runtime.addShutdownHook(
                    new Thread(
                        new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                killALData();
                            }
                        }
                    )
                );

                char[] c = new char[1];
                while(c[0] != 'q') {    
                try {
                    BufferedReader buf =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    System.out.println("Press a key and hit ENTER: " +
                                       "'p' to play, 's' to stop, 'h' to pause and 'q' to quit");
                    buf.read(c);
                    switch(c[0]) {
                        case 'p':
                            // Pressing 'p' will begin playing the sample.
                            al.alSourcePlay(source[0]);
                            break;
                        case 's':
                            // Pressing 's' will stop the sample from playing.
                            al.alSourceStop(source[0]);
                            break;
                        case 'h':
                            // Pressing 'n' will pause (hold) the sample.
                            al.alSourcePause(source[0]);
                            break;
                        }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }

        } // class SingleStaticSource
```